# args-out-of-range error with ac-html

Tags: completion, auto-complete-mode, web-mode, html

I tried using [`ac-html`](https://github.com/zhangkaiyulw/ac-html) recently since I'm an `auto-complete` user and I'd like to have HTML completion in `html-mode` and `web-mode` buffers. However, it has been acting somewhat strangely and throws an error whenever I type anything in an `html-mode` or `web-mode` buffer:

```
auto-complete error: (args-out-of-range <name-of-current-buffer> 0 2)
```

As a result of this error, `auto-complete-mode` is disabled in the current buffer. However, perhaps even more strangely, if I turn on `auto-complete-mode` after it was disabled by the error, everything works as expected and I get auto-completion. Yet, this only seems to happen in `html-mode` buffers; i.e., I do not get auto-completion after re-enabling `auto-complete-mode` in `web-mode` buffers.

I have `ac-html` set up for both `html-mode` and `web-mode` like so in my init files:

```
;; Better completion for html-mode
(defun setup-ac-for-html ()
  (require 'ac-html)
  (require 'ac-html-default-data-provider)
  (ac-html-enable-data-provider 'ac-html-default-data-provider)
  (ac-html-setup)
  (setq ac-sources '(ac-source-html-tag
                     ac-source-html-attr
                     ac-source-html-attrv)))

;; Better completion for web-mode
(defun setup-ac-for-web-mode ()
  (require 'ac-html)
  (require 'ac-html-default-data-provider)

  (add-to-list 'web-mode-ac-sources-alist
               '("html" . (ac-source-html-tag
                           ac-source-html-attr
                           ac-source-html-attrv))))

...

(add-hook 'html-mode-hook                      'setup-ac-for-html)
(add-hook 'web-mode-before-auto-complete-hooks 'setup-ac-for-web-mode)
```

How can I get this error to stop happening so that I don't have to re-enable `auto-complete-mode` after said error? Also, why does this re-enabling seemingly not work for `web-mode`?

I'm using Emacs 25.1.1 on OS X 10.11.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've come up with a couple of hacky fixes for these problems and have been able to sufficiently enable auto-completion with `auto-complete-mode` via said fixes. I managed to get `web-mode` completion working by adjusting my configuration to be in accordance with [the code from their website for setting up auto-completion](http://web-mode.org):

```
(defun setup-ac-for-web-mode ()
       (setq web-mode-ac-sources-alist
             '(("css"  . (ac-source-css-property))
               ("html" . (ac-source-words-in-buffer ac-source-abbrev)))))
    ...
    (add-to-list 'ac-modes 'web-mode)
    ...
    (add-hook 'web-mode-before-auto-complete-hooks 'setup-ac-for-web-mode)
```

Mind you this new setup for `web-mode` is no longer using `ac-html`, but it seems that `web-mode` has provided their own `auto-complete` sources, which work well enough for me. The next fix that I've made enables `ac-html`to work for `html-mode` itself:

```
(add-hook 'html-mode-hook
          #'(lambda ()
              (run-with-idle-timer 0.1 nil (lambda () (progn
                                                        (auto-complete-mode 1)
                                                        (auto-complete-mode -1)
                                                        (auto-complete-mode 1))))))
```

As you can see, it's quite crude and all that it does is automate the process of turning `auto-complete-mode` on, off, and on again shortly after `html-mode` is initially invoked in a given buffer. I'm not sure why that works, but it does and now I have auto-completion for `html-mode` as well as `web-mode`.